# Can I playback a CAN log file to a CAN input on V2X device?

Tags: canoe, canalyzer

I am currently working on implementing a Cohda DSRC V2X device that takes a vehicle CAN input. I don't have access to the vehicle and want to simulate the input with a prerecorded CAN log file from it. If possible, we want to playback the CAN log file into the V2X device. I was directed to look into Vector CANoe/CANalyzer products. After looking into their products, documentation, forums, and FAQs, I have not been able to determine if this is possible. So, can this be done, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use a replay block in Vector CANoe environment if the log file is in Vector supported format and you do not use any secure communication.

For reference please see:
[Vector Public Knowledge Area on logging formats](https://support.vector.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0011536&sys_kb_id=cef442e41b2614148e9a535c2e4bcb05&spa=1), especially the note on the bottom.